# How do I use the [[#Headers],[Column]] notation with a table ListObject instead of a "TableName"?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert a recorded macro to a generic VBA script (my first one ever).  The recorded macro produced specific names in the code like Sheet8 and Table5.  I need these to be determined dynamically in the code, and so far, I've been able to figure that out...

```
'This table name needs to be dynamically determined...
Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, myRng, , xlNo)
```

However I need help figuring out how to convert these lines...

```
Range("Table5[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
```

...to something that uses the myTable ListObject.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myRng As Range, rngH1 As Range
'where to place the table
Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5:H10")
'create table
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, myRng, , xlNo)
'get firts header
Set rngH1 = myTable.HeaderRowRange.Columns(1)
'select first header (assuming that Sheet where table placed is active)
rngH1.Select
```

If you want to find header using it's name, you can do:

```
'select header "Column3" (assuming that Sheet where table placed is active)
myTable.ListColumns("Column3").Range(1).Select
```

also may be interesting: [how to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)